# jQuery AJAX SOAP Request returns 405

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap

I am trying to do a SOAP request with jQuery AJAX that works when using a SOAP client. Using the jQuery implementation always returns

'XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?op=GetClasses. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405'

All solutions I have found talk about changing something on the service-side (the endpoint I am querying). However, I am a consumer of an API that I cannot influence and as I said it works when using a SOAP client.

Here's the request from the SOAP client (Boomerang) that works:

```
POST https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5/GetClasses

<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <ns:GetClasses>
        <ns:Request>
            <ns:SourceCredentials>
                <ns:SourceName>##PLACEHOLDER##</ns:SourceName>
                <ns:Password>##PLACEHOLDER##</ns:Password>
                <ns:SiteIDs>
                    <ns:int>-99</ns:int>
                </ns:SiteIDs>
            </ns:SourceCredentials>
            <ns:XMLDetail>Bare</ns:XMLDetail>
            <ns:PageSize>0</ns:PageSize>
            <ns:CurrentPageIndex>0</ns:CurrentPageIndex>
        </ns:Request>
    </ns:GetClasses>
</x:Body>
```

and this is my jQuery implementation of this call:

```
var webServiceURL = 'https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?op=GetClasses';
var soapMessage = '<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5"> <x:Header/> <x:Body> <ns:GetClasses> <ns:Request> <ns:SourceCredentials> <ns:SourceName>##PLACEHOLDER##</ns:SourceName> <ns:Password>##PLACEHOLDER##</ns:Password> <ns:SiteIDs> <ns:int>-99</ns:int> </ns:SiteIDs> </ns:SourceCredentials> <ns:XMLDetail>Bare</ns:XMLDetail> <ns:PageSize>0</ns:PageSize> <ns:CurrentPageIndex>0</ns:CurrentPageIndex> </ns:Request> </ns:GetClasses> </x:Body> </x:Envelope>';

function CallService()
{
    $.ajax({
      url: webServiceURL,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "xml",
      data: soapMessage,
      contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
      success: OnSuccess,
      error: OnError
    });

    return false;
}

function OnSuccess(data, status)
{
    alert(data.d);
}

function OnError(request, status, error)
{
    alert('error');
}
```

Any idea at which point I am going wrong? For the WebServiceURL I have also used https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx which didn't help much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must POST the message at this endpoint:

```
https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx
```

You can also add `crossDomain: true` to you Ajax call (I think it's the default in this case, but it makes the intention more explicit).

Then, the service should allow the call by setting the proper [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers). If the server is not, then you can't make the call from JavaScript because of [the same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

There is also the possibility that you are not making the call right.

Just to make sure that CORS is the problem, (JUST FOR TESTING) you can [turn off the same origin policy in Chrome](http://joshuamcginnis.com/2011/02/28/how-to-disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/) and see if you can call the service from JavaScript. Once you get a successful call from JavaScript, turn the security back on and redo the test. If it fails then the web service is not properly configured to allow CORS request and you need to either:

- have your on backend to act as a proxy for the call. Then you can host the JavaScript client on the same domain and do the call to your proxy (doesn't even need to be a SOAP call any longer if your proxy converts the SOAP response into a simpler API);
- talk to the guys that implemented the web service and ask them to fix the CORS headers.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Bogdan, thanks for your quick response. I have tried disabling the security flags and Chrome warns me excitedly about it when I do (so it seems to work). However, tracking the calls that are going out with postman, Chrome is still sending out an OPTIONS call. It seems as though mindbody can't handle OPTIONS because I always get a 'HHTP verb used not allowed' error. Even if I am sending that call from another client such as postman or boomerang. I will ask mindbody to check that. In the meantime, any ideas how to force Chrome to do an actual POST instead of an OPTIONS? Thanks again!

Comment: and I changed the URL, with no effects however

Comment: @Matze: Even if you could force Chrome not to send an OPTIONS, later, in a "non hacked for testing" browser the request won't work because CORS explicitly mandates that the POST should have an OPTIONS pre-flight. This is something like warning the server that a CORS request will soon follow. If the server recognizes the OPTIONS then it will respond with the proper CORS headers and say "sure... let me have the request, I can handle CORS requests".....

Comment: ... If on the other hand it doesn't recognize the OPTIONS then it is not configured to handle CORS requests in which case it's better for the request to fail then for the server to process a cross domain POST like it was a POST from it's own domain. This does not fully make sense for a web service since most web service requests will be from other domains, but CORS was designed for the web semantics, not for how web services operate.

Comment: ... So it seems like this is not a JS/browser issue but the web service not supporting (or being wrongly configured for) CORS.

Comment: Hey Bogdan, it certainly seems that way. I have agreed to a different solution with my client as I didn't want to wait for mindbody's help. Thanks for your timely assistance though!